# How to subtract one from a memory location without using minus?

Tags: assembly, x86

I got this question on one of the interview question websites. The solution will be a code written in assembly language. I'm not very good in assembly and just wondering how it can be done. I know without minus we can subtract by adding (-1). That is taking 2's compliment. But exactly how should I write instruction is difficult for me. Any help will be appreciated.

I got something like this:

```
MOV AX,b 
Taking 2's compliment here 
ADD AX,above mentioned command
```

I'm using X86.
Thanks

Comment: Are you using x86?  How about this? http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly/Arithmetic#Increment_and_Decrement

Comment: Pretty 2, very pretty 2. Bright and beautiful, and so very even.

Answer (score 2):

Since there are several ways to subtract one, and because it's not entirely clear what is and isn't allowed, I'll post several possible solutions - take your pick.

Using `add` with negative one:

```
mov AX, b
add AX, -1
mov b, AX
```

Using decrement:

```
mov AX, b
dec AX
mov b, AX
```

Using negation + addition:

```
mov AX, b
neg AX
add AX, 1 ; inc AX also works
neg AX
```

There are countless other possibilities.

Comment: Just one doubt, I want to decrement 1 from a memory location X86. Is moving the value to AX a correct move ?

Comment: It's just as valid to move the value to AX first, decrement it, then write it back to memory as it is to decrement the value in memory directly.

Answer (score 0):

```
mov CX,b
loop Here
@Here:
mov b,CX
```

Comment: this works b/c you're using the loop count register?

Comment: @JayInNyc yep, `loop` decrements `CX`

Answer (score 0):

If this is X86 or some other processors, then you have an add immediate to memory (Intel format)

```
value   dd     1234            ;original value (could be any value)
;       ...
        add    value, -1
```

or just decrement from memory:

```
        dec     value
```

or something convoluted:

```
        neg     value
        not     value
```

Comment: so can't I use MOV and DEC commands as one has stated in the answer above ?

Comment: You could but there no need for a mov since add immediate of -1 or dec can be used directly with a memory location, without using any registers.

Comment: Use decrement or go for bitoperations. Whoever want to see your solution perhaps will be surprised if bitoperations occurr.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the most obvious way to subtract one without using minus is:

```
        sub AX,1
```

This has the advantage over `dec` that it sets the flags accordingly.